# Delete MapBox GeoJSON Annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapbox

I am trying to find out how to delete my MapBox annotations.  I have been following the MapBox Example below
https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/

If I add my annotations using GeoJSON, I am unsure how I can delete these annotations by a press of the button.

To initialise the source I am using
`-initWithIdentifier:URL:options:`

In MapViewDidFinishLoading I call

```
url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: filterCat, ofType: "geojson")!)

source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts",
                                url: url,
                                options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])

style.addSource(source)
```

filterCat is set in ViewDidLoad.

With a button press I would like to call a different file by setting filterCat to something else.

However, I am struggling to be able to call

```
    style.removeSource(source)
```

Not sure where I should call this??
I set this in my VC (above ViewDidLoad)

```
var url: URL!
var style: MGLStyle!
var source: MGLShapeSource!
```

Thinking I could delete the source, but keeps on giving an error of nil

Comment: [This feature is being tracked](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6177), but there is not a timeline on it. There may be a workaround for your use case, but would need a little more information. Are you using `MGLShapeSource`? If so, which [initializer](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.6/Classes/MGLShapeSource.html#/Initializing%20a%20Source) are you using?

Comment: To initialise the source I am using   
`-initWithIdentifier:URL:options:`
In MapViewDidFinishLoading I call
`url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: filterCat, ofType: "geojson")!)
        
        source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "clusteredPorts",
                                    url: url,
                                    options: [.clustered: true, .clusterRadius: icon.size.width])
        
        style.addSource(source)`

filterCat is set in ViewDidLoad.

With a button press I would like to call a different file by setting filterCat to something else

Comment: I added some extra info.